# Mentioning client name in Roles and Resposibility document to ACS

Tags: visa, australia, australian-citizens

I am planning to apply for Australian permanent residency and being a software engineer from a multi-national company I have only worked for one client. Would it be OK to mention the client's name in the Roles and Responsibility document to the Australian Computer Society.

It would be great if someone can share a successful template.

Comment: It might help if you define your terms. I assume PR is permanent resident status, since that's a pretty common abbreviation. But what is MNC and ACS?

Comment: MNC is for Multi National Company and ACS is Australian Computer Society the team who evaluates your elevant job experience in the job code you applied PR. And I am dilemna that whether I should specify my client name or not in my roles and responsibilities document to ACS

Comment: I have expanded the abbreviations for you.  In general, when someone makes a comment asking for clarification, you should [edit] your question to include the requested information.

Comment: When you say "client", do you mean your employer, or do you mean a company who had a contract with your employer for the supply of services?  "Client" normally means the latter.

Comment: correct the client here referes to company who I (my employer) provide services to.